# Solve the equation with 4-th degree variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation
$$(x-5)^2(3-x)^2-4(x+5)(3-x)-48=(x+1)^2$$
I haven't learn how to solve this one please solve clearly. Its from Analysis with Algebra Class Topic:Quadratic Equations

Comment: Hi! please use [latex](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question, as it makes it much easier to read and shows that you put effort into the question.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-5%29%5E2%283-x%29%5E2-4%28x%2B5%29%283-x%29-48%3D%28x%2B1%29%5E2) knows how to do it but doesn't tell

Comment: @lhf it is probably because the equation can be rewritten as $((x-5)(3-x)-4)^2 - 5(x-7)^2 = 0$. However, I can't figure out a way to deduce this w/o a CAS :-(

Comment: By expanding you get: $$x^{4}-16x^{3}+97x^{2}-234x+116=0$$ Applying the usual $u=x-b/4$, we get: $$u^{4}+u^{2}+30u-36=0$$

Comment: Which is then factored to $$\left(u^{2}+3\right)^{2}-5\left(u-3\right)^{2}$$ Not sure how to get there by hand.